# Hash tables, same record on each hash table cell

Tags: c, hashtable

There is a word dictionary in a text file. I will hash all these words. I wrote some code yet there is a problem. Last word takes place on each hash table records.

```
main()
{
   FILE *fp;
   char word[100];
   char *hash[569];
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<569;i++)
      hash[i]="NULL";


   int m=569;
   int z =569;
   int mm=568;
   char w;

   int key;
   int j;
   int hash1;
   int hash2;
   fp=fopen("smallDictionary.txt","r");
   int counter =0;
   while(fscanf(fp,"%s",word)!=EOF)
   {
    j=0;
    counter++;

      for(i=key=0;i<strlen(word);i++)
         key+=(word[i]-'a')*26*i;
      hash1=key%m;
      hash2=1+(key%mm);
      while(hash[(hash1+j*hash2)%m]!="NULL")
      {
             j++;          
      }
      hash[(hash1+j*hash2)%m] = word;
   }

  for(i=0;i<569;i++)
      printf("%s ",hash[i]);

   fclose(fp);
}
```

End the result on console.

[image]

As it seen, as last word of dictionary, "your" keyword repeats.

Dictionary content :

> a about above absolutely acceptable add adjacent after algorithm all
>   along also an analyses and any anyone are argument as assignment
>   assume at available be been below bird body but by can cannot
>   capitalization case center chain chaining changing characters check
>   checker checkers checking choose class code collision collisions
>   command compilation compile compiled complexity conform consist
>   containing contains convenience convert correcting corrections create
>   created cross deal debugging december decide deducted deleted
>   departmental dictionary discover discussed divides document
>   documentation due dynamically e each easiest encountered enough error
>   errors etc even exactly example executable expand experience factor
>   fair fall file files find first following font for forth found four
>   friday from function functions g gain general generate generated
>   generating geoff get gird given good graders grows guide guidelines
>   had hair handle has hash hashing have head header help helped hold
>   homework hour how i if in include including incorrect information
>   input insert inserted insertions instructions into is ispell it
>   keeping known kuenning last length less letter letters like line
>   linear list load long longer longest look looked low lower maintained
>   many match may messages method midnight might misspelled mistake mode
>   more most must my name named names necessary need never next no note
>   number of on once one only options or original other otherwise output
>   overview page pair pedantic points policies possibility possible
>   prefer primary probing problem produce produces professor program
>   purpose quack quadratic quick read reason reasonably refer reference
>   rehashing reinitialized report resubmit rid same save separate
>   separated seriously should similar simple simplify single size so
>   something specifications specified spell spelling standard statistics
>   string strong submission submit submitted successfully suggest
>   suggested support suppose table tech th than that the them then there
>   these this those three through thursday times title to together tooth
>   track traditionally transposed trial try turing udder under understand
>   unlike up use used useful using usual variant variants version wall
>   ward warning was way we when whenever which while whitespace who why
>   wild will wind wire wiry with word words works write written wrong you
>   your

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hash[(hash1+j*hash2)%m] = word;
```

That just assigns the address of `word` to the hash entry. Which is always the same. And at the end of the loop the contents of `word` is obviously going to be the last thing that was read by fscanf. SO you need something like:

```
hash[(hash1+j*hash2)%m] = strdup(word);
```

`strdup` allocates heap memory so don't forget to free it when the hash table is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

All pointers in the hashtable points to the same variable: The `word` array. Whatever is the last string you put in `word`, will be the string printed in your output.

You need to allocate memory for each word, either by making `hash` an array of arrays and copy the word into the secondary array, or using e.g. `strdup` to allocate the string dynamically.

---

More graphically, it could be though of as this:

```
+---------+
| hash[x] | -\       +------+
+---------+   >--- > | word |
| hash[y] | -/       +------+
+---------+     +--------+
| hash[z] | --> | "NULL" |
+---------+     +--------+
```

Here both the entry `x` and `y` points to `word`, while entry `z` points to the string literal `"NULL"` you initialized all entries to.